# Why do graphics drawn with GetDC(0); disappear as soon as a window moves over them?

Tags: c++, winapi

If you use the following code to draw a rectangle the rectangle goes away as soon as anything moves over it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HDC screenDC = ::GetDC(0);
    ::Rectangle(screenDC, 200, 200, 300, 300);

    int exit; cin >> exit;
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to receive a callback when my Rectangle gets destroyed so that I can repaint it? Is there any way to change the color of my rectangle? Is there a **good** comprehensive tutorial that covers this?

Comment: Petzold's book goes over GDI in great length. Don't forget about GDI+ etc. as well.

Comment: It's not _your_ rectangle.  If you want a bit of screen real estate, then you need to create a window.  Drawing to the desktop DC is like spraying graffiti on someone else's wall: don't be surprised if the owner paints over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the screen is being constantly updated. Things are being redrawn over your rectangle and this is why it's disappearing. (Such as your window)

**Edit:** You can draw your rectangle in a loop to keep it there. You can also use this loop for application logic and event handling if needed.

**NOTE:** What you should do will depend on what the application does. Leave this method as a last resort because it is quite CPU intensive. (It would be less CPU intensive with sleeps in the loop, but you can't guarantee that a sleep will give you a correct pause time.)

Comment: I guess it'd depend on what the application is for :/
I don't know any other solution however. I guess I could add a disclaimer to this answer.

Comment: It's just a hello world application. Maybe some fun practical things but it's not going into production or anything.

Comment: Then Brandon Moretz solution all the way.

Comment: @user1873073: Of course, but the OS wasn't designed for toy programs. If you're not following the design, you're not making it easier for yourself. The "good comprehensive tutorials" will show you how you _should_ do things. In particular, when you create your own window, your program will be woken up _exactly_ at the moment painting is needed.

Comment: Much inaccurate information here, moving mouse doesn't necessarily mean redraw, moving a window either. Performance implications of your suggestions have been mentioned.

Comment: I'm basing this on information I acquired through experimentation, so I'm potentially wrong. What I did was set all the pixels on my screen blue and move the mouse, click, select, drag, etc...

Comment: @MSalters, I beg to differ. I make toy programs all the time :) Some of them are actually pretty useful, some are fun to use, and some are a fun way to learn.

Comment: @user1873073 please don't accept this answer. Even the author says so!

Answer (score 8):

If you want to draw a rectangle,it's best to do so in your own window. You will get `WM_PAINT` events any time your window becomes visible again and needs repainting. The OS isn't accidentally called "Windows"; most things graphical are centered around windows.

If you don't want to show anything but that rectangle, make the window just as big as the rectangle.

Comment: I usually prefer a window with a colour key over the whole screen. It depends on what you do with it I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle [WM_PAINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in your winproc and each time you handle the message, redraw your image. If you don't, the window will just redraw itself with the default background color.

See: [this](http://suite101.com/article/win32-drawing-wm-paint-processing-a26003) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1988/Guide-to-WIN32-Paint-for-beginners) for more detail on GDI.

Comment: Of course, you're not magically going to get `WM_PAINT` for the entire screen.